# the node went into the draining state after making keyspaces on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

While setting up the Cassandra on 15 nodes, we found that one of the node went into the draining state after making keyspaces on Cassandra.
We don’t know why the node went into the draining state. We are working with ALL CONSISTENCY setup, so in such case we are not able to query Cassandra.
Later we were trying to upgrade DC/OS to latest version along with latest Cassandra version, but this upgradation resulted in corruption of data on all the nodes. From this point on we were not able to add existing data as it was getting corrupted.

Comment: There may be schema mismatch. Have you installed same version on all cassandra nodes? can you paste the error here?

Comment: Yes !! installed same version on all cassandra nodes. There are no logs as I was unable query it as all were in  ALL CONSISTENCY setup.

Comment: You can change the consistency. login CQLSH and CONSISTENCY <>.